# google shared drive search api

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api, google-search-api, google-drive-shared-drive

i have lots of google shared drive and many content in it , currently trying to search some query and i got only limited result , but when i am trying to search those query in drive i got many results.

response through API : -
[res.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wB0R3.png)

my code is : -

```
try {
    Drive.files.list({
        q: "name contains 'jeet' ",
     // q: "fullText contains 'jeet' ", -- this is also get 2-3 result
        supportsAllDrives: true
    }, function(err, res) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
        if (res) {
            console.log(res)
            fs.writeFile("./res.json", JSON.stringify(res.data, null, 2), function(err, res) {})
        }
    })
} catch (error) {

}
```

when i actually search in google drive : - [i got thousands of resualts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4qIw.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your situation, how about adding the properties of `corpora` and `includeItemsFromAllDrives` as follows?

#### Modified script:

##### From:

```js
Drive.files.list({
    q: "name contains 'jeet' ",
 // q: "fullText contains 'jeet' ", -- this is also get 2-3 result
    supportsAllDrives: true
}, function(err, res) {
```

##### From:

```js
Drive.files.list({
    q: "name contains 'jeet' ",
 // q: "fullText contains 'jeet' ", -- this is also get 2-3 result
    supportsAllDrives: true,
    corpora: "allDrives", // Added
    includeItemsFromAllDrives: true, // Added
}, function(err, res) {
```

#### Reference:

- [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)